# Cast to map object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have error

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '() => string'

```
this.selectedValue.display = headerOcr.author.profession;

private selectedValue: IDocumentType = {
    id: '1',
    display: () => '',
    label: ''
}
```

this is are default initialized value for "selectedValue"

What I should do to `headerOcr.author.profession`? `display; () => ''` should have const type.

Comment: try () => { return '' }

Comment: You're assigning to `display` a function. If display type is a string, you may want to invoke the function immediately by writing `display: ( () => '' )()` or plain out write `display: ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '() => string'

Typescript expect that all of your object properties will be strings, so there are two ways:

1. Return value in `display: () => return '',`
2. Change your `IDocumentType` interface like this:

`IDocumentType {
  /*...*/
  display: () => string
  /*...*/
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can not pass a function if you defined it as a `string` type. Either you change the definition of `headerOcr` or evaluate the function call before passing it to display.

The change of definition would look like these:

```
IDocumentType {
  display: () => string
}
```

With that you have to use it as `IDocumentType.display()`